# Run AndroidViewClient from Java

Tags: android, androidviewclient

I want to create a testing environment for Android apps / UIs based on `monkeyrunner`. My goal is to provide an environment that automatically tests `Activities` and their UI elements like `EditText` or `Button`, not by randomly creating touch/ gesture events but doing 'meaningful' stuff like finding an `EditText` that's labeled 'email' and enter an email adress into it.
I did some research on what tools are readily available and found `ChimpChat`, [AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) and of course [dtmilano.blogspot.de](http://dtmilano.blogspot.de/).

I'm not familiar with python development, so my question is if it makes any sense (and is even possible) to try to use AVC from Java with Jython (I know I still have to learn some Python) or if that would be a unnecessary complication of things and I should try to develop such a thing in plain Python.

Any input would be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) tries to be keep the same API style you are accustom to use from Java, so it won't be difficult to learn it.

For example, instead of different approaches taken by other tools, **AndroidViewClient** uses a more familiar

```
vc.findViewById('id/some_id')
```

to find Views.
It also introduces natural extensions to this API like

```
vc.findViewWithText('sometext')
```

and

```
vc.findViewWithText(re.compile('[a-z]*'))
```

To simplify things even more, **[culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/culebra)** was introduced some time ago. This tool will help you generate scripts that you can adapt to your needs with just a few changes.

Let's say you start **Contacts** application in your emulator or device, and press **Add**, you are presented with the **New Contact** entry form, and according to the example you mentioned you would like to enter an email address.
Once the **New Contact** form is displayed, run:

```
$ culebra --verbose-comments --output=contacts.py
```

and then edit the generated script `contacts.py`. Locate a line where the **Email** field is obtained, it should look something like:

```
...
# class=android.widget.EditText text="Email"
no_id57 = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("id/no_id/57")
...
```

and add

```
no_id57.type('donald@example.com')
```

save the script. Run it. And you'll see how, if everything goes well, the email address is entered.

I'll be creating a more detailed example in a separate post at [dtmilano.blogspot.com](http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/).

If you still want to use Java, strictly speaking **AndroidViewClient** could be ported to Java (patches and sponsorships are welcome) or you can use [UiAutomator](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html) to create similar tests.